# How would I implement an existing Angular Theme over MEAN.js

Tags: angularjs, themes, mean-stack, meanjs

I have MEAN.js installed, along with an Angular theme that I would like to replace the default MEAN Angular theme with, in looking at the structure of each, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement it, does anyone have an approach or perhaps a link to a tutorial for this.

Comment: hard to understand what your specific problems are

Comment: Do you mean the bootstrap theme? Angular theme doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the Bootstrap theme, you can place the theme files in a convenient directory and then update the `config/assets/default.js` file with the path to the theme files.